# How to hide a particular text in a textbox for wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my web browser app for wp7, i have a textbox for the URL's(named as UrlTextBox), in that i don't need the **http://** to be visible even when the page is navigating or navigated. I don't know how to hide a particular text in a textbox. If i try to omit the http:// permanently then there will an error in my app. Can anybody help me with this? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You should create a second string which has no http:// and you show this string in your textbox and use the other one in your navigation.

Comment: @BigL I am new to c#, do you have any samples or can you post your codes here???

Comment: Matt Lacey-s example shows how you can do it without a second variable and it is easier if you are new to c#

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess you're probably doing something like:

```
webBrowser.Navigate(urlTextBox.Text);
```

Instead you could just do:

```
webBrowser.Navigate("http://" + urlTextBox.Text);
```

Obviously with appropriate checks, etc.

OR

```
if (urlTextBox.Text.StartsWith("http://")
{
    urlTextBox.Text = urlTextBox.Text.SubString(7);
}
```